# Show selected row information in another table

Tags: java, swing, jtable

Hello everybody I just created two `JTable` components and two array lists.

The first `ArrayList` contains questions' data (question ID, question Description, Key answer) and another array list contains options' data (option Id, option description).

First table gets questions data from first array list and shows it.
And each question in this table has multi options.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJS5u.png)

I want when I select row in questions' table, the options of this question will appear. How can I do that?

Below I post two functions that are used to show data:

```
 private void showQuestions(){
    int rowCount= question_table.getRowCount();
    Object question[]=null;
    DefaultTableModel t = (DefaultTableModel) question_table.getModel();
    for(int i=0;i<examQuestions.size();i++){
        question =new Object[]{examQuestions.get(i).question_id,examQuestions.get(i).questionDescription,examQuestions.get(i).keyAnswer};
        t.addRow(question);
    }

    question_table.getSelectionModel().addListSelectionListener(new ListSelectionListener(){
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent event) {

    }
});
}
private void showOption(){ 
    int rowCount = option_table.getRowCount();
    Object option[]=null;
    DefaultTableModel t = (DefaultTableModel) option_table.getModel();
        for(int i = 0;i <=examQuestions.size()-1;i++){
            for(int j = 0; j <=examQuestions.get(i).answerOptions.size()-1;j++){  
            option = new Object[]{ j+1, examQuestions.get(i).answerOptions.get(j)};
            t.addRow(option);
            }
        }
}
```

Comment: You need to map the questions to the options, so that, given a question, you can get the options/answers simply

Comment: OK I know that but how can I map  the questions to the options?!

Comment: You're using a OO language, `Question` should have a "options" and "answer" properties